# 3 Axis Gimbal Stabilization System can replace with 3 Axis Accelerometer

Tags: quadcopter, sensors, accelerometer

i have "TAROT ZYX-GS 3-Axis Gimbal Stabilization System ZYX13" sensor that gives me the value of Roll tilt and Pan.The 3 axis accelerometer give me the value of x y and z.so can we use the Gimbal stabiliztion system in place of accelerometer[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3-axis gimbal stabilization system internally combines a 3-axis gyroscope and 3-axis accelerometer. It outputs PWM signals necessary for maintaining an orientation.  The outputs are typically meant to drive RC servos.

This *might* be enough for your use-case, but it is dependent on the details.

But generally, a gimbal stabilization system is not the same as accelerometer. An accelerometer operates at a lower level and provides x/y/z acceleration components at the measured instant in time only.  This gimbal system is outputting the corrections that would be needed to hold an orientation.  You might be able to derive acceleration from that to some extent, but that is not what it is intended for.

Comment: In quadCopter we need a 3 axis accelerometer(IMU),can we use this Tarot zxy in  quadcopter

Comment: I think you should post a new question. Something like "Can I use a 3D gimbal system as a simplistic quadcopter flight controller?"  I think the answer is  'no', but I'm not positive.